# get single record data AngularFireDatabase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Below is my screenshot database:

[image]

I want to get single course - by id,
here is my code:

Service:

```
 getSingle(uid: string) {
    return this.db
      .object(`courses/${uid}`)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(res => res.payload.val()));
  }
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.coursesService.getSingle('Kyric46r714Kibjqw2E').subscribe(item => {
      console.log(item);
    });
```

i am getting `null` - in `console.log(item)`

Moreover, if i change my service to this:

```
 getSingle(uid: string) {
    return this.db
      .object(`courses/${uid}`)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(res => res.payload.key)); < ------------
  }
```

i am getting in `console.log(item)` my key - `Kyric46r714Kibjqw2E`, as i should.

why the val() method doesn't work?

Thanks for help in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the dash `-` next to you `id` to retrieve the data inside of it:

```
this.coursesService.getSingle('-Kyric46r714Kibjqw2E').subscribe(item
```